# Spring MVC Websocket + sockjs https

Tags: websocket, sockjs

I am implementing WebSocket using spring MVC ws in crossing domain environment. I tested successfully with HTTP but got the problem with https.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://server:port/ws/650/vmm0vcx2/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 stomp.js:10 
Whoops! Lost connection to undefined 

var socket = new SockJS('wss//server:port/ws');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/datafile', function(response){
                var json = JSON.parse(response.body);
                console.log(json);
            });
        });
```

**Spring config**:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/fieldmetrics-api">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws" allowed-origins="*">
            <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>
```

I set `<async-supported>true</async-supported>`  for servlet and filter.
I am a newbie of websocket, please help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?